# Calculating percentage of a parent's "parent" total in Excel PivotTable

Tags: excel, pivot-table, percentage

[image]

I have the PivotTable above and I'm trying to calculate a percentage based on the parent's parent (grandparent?!)  row total opposed to the direct parent row total. For example, at the minute 134 is being divided by 153 (by using % of Parent Row Total) to give 87.58%. The calculate I'm trying to do is is 134/169 (which is the total of Category A). I'm using Category A as an example but there's 100 of categories that this needs to be calculated for, hence hoping that a Pivot can do it opposed to me having to do calculations as such.

Thanks,

Comment: You could simply implement a calculated field and do the division in there. Yet, you should note that the results may not always be correct: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/211470

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the field -> Field settings -> Show data as -> '% of Total'

Comment: This then allows you to choose the grandparent row, or any other level of parent to group by (I'm leaving this as a comment to remind myself; I ignored this answer the first time I saw it because I didn't read the question and assumed this was % of grand total only).